# Brews Python 2.7.7 shows up as 2.7.5

Tags: python, homebrew

I installed a fresh version of Python via

```
brew install python
```

Also

```
brew info python
```

tells me that it is at version 2.7.7.

I seem to remember that the python OSX Mavericks ships with is 2.5. So that

```
python --version
```

gives me 2.7.5 makes even less sense.

Also

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

should be the Homebrew version, correct?

I'm lost. Does anybody know, why my Python isn't version 2.7.7?

Comment: Mavericks ships with 2.7.5.

Comment: I suspect, however, that this may not be related to the author's `python --version` being `2.7.5`. `which python` pointing to the brew location tells me that author had a version of python installed with brew already, and just hadn't switched to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell brew that you want to switch to the version of python you just installed. To do that, type:

```
brew switch python 2.7.7
```

in your command line. This may not work if the version you installed is actually `2.7.7_2`. In that case, just replace `2.7.7` with `2.7.7_2` above and run it again. Once this is done, you'll have to reload your environment to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Python from my experience doesn't do an upgrade in the sense we would like it. Basically it will install python but not overwrite the old version. If you look in your main drive you will prolly see Python 2.7.7 and Python 2.7.5 
usually in Windows its: C:\Python27 
It doesn't really show the last digit (which from my knowledge refers to bugs fixed in the version), so it may overwrite unless it is an entirely new version. '
But I would check first if you have two files of Python. If you do then change your PATH variable environment to point to the latest and delete the old version. 
That's my suggestion but I use Windows and pip install, so hopefully it is not too different.